# Intellisense in razor/cshtml files not working (Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: razor, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

We are used to intellisense everywhere and suddenly it doesn't work.

To my frustration, this was only the case on my work computer, the installation at home *does* work. Both has been updated to version 17.5.0, but I think the problem also existed with the previous version (on my work computer) - it's been a while since I did any Razor coding.

I've searched for like issues, but every question were related to older versions of VS.

I finally found a mention of a new version of the Razor editor, with description of how to deactivate this and reactivate the old one. To my surprise this worked:

Open **Tools / Options** and navigate to **Text Editor / HTML / Advanced**, here you find a setting: *"Use legacy Razor editor for ASP.NET CORE"*.
Change the setting to **true** and intellisense are back!

Nice to find a solution, but!

- This is just a work-around - there must be something else wrong with the installation on my work computer.
- There is a team working on a new Razor editor - it would be nice to use this new (and hopefully) improved version.

Any suggestions how to actually solve this (not just work-around), will be appreciated!

Comment: 1. Send feedback through VS.  The product team can help try to track this down and the logs included in that feedback help. 2. Check for errors in the Output window, it may be an issue like https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-when-opening-any-razor-file/10261368 (root cause, antivirus was causing the language server to fail to start)

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: Indeed, did you solve it? I think I have the same problem. But with a fresh Visual Studio 2022 install (VS 17.8.1).

Comment: I haven't had the time to look into the problem, so no - no solution just yet, The problem exists also in a fresh install of Visual Studio - quite annoying...

Comment: This did fix it to me perfectly. Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### OK - finally an update to handle this issue!

Update Visual Studio to 17.8.+ (.Net 8/C# 12 etc) - in this version they (the Visual Studio team) has included a setting to enable colors for the new Razor editor, see the release notes [here!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#background-color-for-c-code)

If you has activated to old editor, deactivate: *Tools*/*Options*/*Text Editor*/*HTML*/*Advanced* - Set **Razor setting** to false (restart VS).

To activate colors: *Tools*/*Options*/*Text Editor*/*Razor (Asp.NET Core)*/*Advanced* - Set **Background for C# code** to *true*.

By the way: This setting defaults to **false**, so not active on new installations!

Comment: I am on 17.8. I have upgraded my Blazor .NET 7 project to .NET 8 and the new setting (Set Background for C# code) did not solve the problem - I need to use the old setting to make things right. When I create a new Blazor Web App everything is fine.

Answer (score -2):

#### Since same VS version on your two computers, and the performance are different, I suggest you to follow the below steps to correct the un-normal one:

***1, repair the VS:***

open your visual studio installer:

[image]

click More -> Repair to repair the VS2022:

[image]

***2, Reset the default settings***

1'' Make sure not effected by the settings of the async user's settings, please [turn off the user settings async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/synchronized-settings-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#turn-off-synchronized-settings-on-a-particular-computer):

[image][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AiKm.png)

[image]

2'' Reset the language environment collection settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### By the way, see whether all of your solutions in the un-normal VS have this issue.

If only one solution have this issue, that should comes from the intelliSense data of the solution.

Follow the below steps to regenerate the intelliSense data:

***1, Close your VS2022***

***2, Open the root folder of the solution, delete the .vs folder(intelliSense data are in this place):***

[image]

***3, Reopen the VS2022, wait for the regenerate steps finished and try test the intelliSense again.***