# Problem with syntax color in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Today I came across an issue with Razor syntax coloring. After turning on the program, everything is fine and after a second it changes as in the attached photo.

[image: Photo of problem]

Additionally, there is no autocomplete in Razor. After adding a space, the colors change in random order.
It's Visual Studio 2022 17.8.4
Maybe someone had a similar problem, thank you in advance for your help.

I restarted Visual Studio, deleted the Visual Studio 2022 folder in Documents on Windows, deleted temporary files, restarted the PC, gave the Visual Studio Installer the repair option, which resulted in downloading the entire program again and installing it.
However, this did not help and the program continued to behave in this strange way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the same problem you are right,

[image]

actually, I think the best thing we can do is use the Visual Studio Report Problem functionality to let them know about the problem and fix it ASAP,

I think [this bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Razor-Syntax-Highlight--Intellisense-Is/10561632?sort=newest) has been reported to them, please upvote the bug, that is the best way to make them fix it

Comment: As you wrote, I reported a bug and i'm closing the topic. I thought it was my fault that something happened, but if others have a similar problem, I can only wait for a fix from Microsoft.

Comment: This post might be help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75558595/intellisense-in-razor-cshtml-files-not-working-visual-studio-2022

Comment: Microsoft fix this issue in VS 2022 17.8.5, Razor syntax back to normal!